# How does Rails know the difference between these two identical expressions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a 4-year old Rails tutorial and I have Rails 4.0.2. I made a model called "Thing" and a controller called "Things". The "Thing" model has one attribute called "data". In my `create` action, I had this line:

```
@thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
```

which results in this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ThingsController#create
```

I found a StackOverflow thread that said I needed to `require` my needed parameters, and that worked just fine.

Before I looked that up I tried putting the hash from my params directly into the `Thing.new()` method and I didn't get an error. I started with this line:

```
puts params[:thing]
```

in my `create` action, typed "12345" in my text field, hit submit and got this in the console:

```
{"data"=>"12345"}
```

So I tried this in the `create` action:

```
@thing = Thing.new({"data" => "12345"})
```

and I didn't get the error. I even confirmed they were identical by doing this:

```
puts params[:thing] == {"data"=>"12345"}
```

and I get "true" on the console. So,

```
Thing.new(params[:thing])
```

gives me the error, but

```
Thing.new({"data"=>"12345"})
```

does not.

How can Rails tell the difference between these two arguments when they seem to be identical?

Comment: I suggest that you use Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. It is free online, and updated for Rails 4.

Answer (score 6):

`params[:thing]` is not the same thing as `{"data" => "12345"}`, they just have the same value when `inspect` is called on them, and `params`'s class overrides `==` to say it's equal to the hash.

Rails 4+ uses [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), which is a security feature to make sure you know what you're putting in your models. Basically, Rails wants to you check the validity of the parameters. It lets you do `Thing.new({"data" => "12345"})` because you, the developer, are creating the Hash directly, and are more trustworthy than someone on the internet calling your server.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're saying that `params` is of a different type than `Hash`, and Rails detects the different type to give it a different treatment?

Comment: Yep, the `ActiveRecord::Base` class treats them differently